# Display json response in grid using angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I am new in angularjs.
I have one json response from rest api, i want to display this resonse into html using angular js.
My problem is that i don't want to display all column from json response.
like i have json response is:

```
{'name':'exmaple name','contact':'123456789','address':'abc street'}
```

I have one arry like ['name','contact']
I want to display only name and contact.

Now array is['name','address']
Then i want to display name and address only.

In this situation all time json give all record from rest api.

how it is possible using angularjs.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ng-repeat?

Comment: Try something before question, If you already have, and something isn't working, post your code

Comment: yes.i haven't problem when disply all column from json,but when page load i have alredy array which column is print or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat can be a good, approach, if you are looking more for desktop like grids, you can use ng-grid or ng-table (paging support, inline edit, sorting, roder by, etc...).

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-table

Cheers
    Braulio